# Shogun on CentOS

Tags: c++, machine-learning, centos, shogun

Have anyone tried installing Shogun on CentOS? Will it work? I tried downloading the source from Shogun site and compile it and it wasn't that easy(also, installed all the requirements needed for shogun). Is it possible to install on CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

yes, shogun is being built on a CentOS7 after each commit.
you can learn about the cmake parameters and how it works from here:
http://buildbot.shogun-toolbox.org/builders/CentOS7%20-%20libshogun

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of shogun, which does not compile with gcc 4.8.5 on CentOS7. This bug will be be fixed until shogun 6.2.0. see [here](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/4306)